# iOS, CFSocket: How Do I Get the Bonjour Name of The Remote End of A CFSocket Connection?

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, networking, bonjour

I have a Bonjour service setup for basic browsing and discovery of local nodes. It works great.

However, I'd like the broadcaster node to know who's connecting. Right now, the CFSocket connection is anonymous, and I don't see an obvious way to determine the name of the remote node's service.

I guess I could provide it by sending a header meta string upon connection, but I'd like to find out if it's possible to use the CFSocket infrastructure to get this basic string.

Comment: Take a look at NSNetService

Comment: Thanks. That's how I do the discovery. However, I only get a socket connection when I am the broadcaster, and someone connects to me. I don't have access to their service; only the socket. I have no problem adding their service name to the socket, if there's any metadata (which I can't find). It looks like I'll have to transmit a meta header. Bit clunky, but it will work.

Comment: Just FYI. I have currently solved this by sending an initial "burst" at connection time that contains the name of the remote service.